# How to create white margins from the left and right side of html page - goal is that all items are centered in the middle with margins

Tags: html, css, margin, center

I have uploaded my code for one page. My goal is to create margins from the left and right sides. The idea is to make the content centered with margins. I have a css code but please keep in mind there is extra code that leads to other pages as well.

For an idea of what needs to be achieved, I have uploaded a link of a site mimicking my goal.
https://aliabdaal.com

```css
.navbar1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  text-align: center;
}

#backroundcolourthing {
  background-color: rgb(247, 251, 255);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px solid green;
  width: auto;
  height: 550px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  /* 1 */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* 2 */
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  /* 3 */
  background: rgb(245, 250, 255);
  /* 4 */
}

.barsection {
  margin: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  /* 5 */
  list-style: none;
  /* 6 */
  margin: auto;
}

nav li {
  padding-left: 3rem;
  /* 7! */
  margin: 3%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif light;
}

.aboutmeh2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Optima;
  text-align: center;
}

.shortsryh2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Optima;
  text-align: center;
}

.para2 {
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 900px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.a {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif light;
  color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.headingforsmth {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.centerimgonline {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.introname {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  text-align: center;
}

.introphrase1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Optima;
  text-align: center;
}

.introphrase3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Optima;
  text-align: center;
}

.post-header {
  margin: 0 -1rem;
  width: calc(100% + 2rem);
  padding: 3rem 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.home__video,
.home__intro {
  margin: 0;
  width: 46%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.para1 {
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 900px;
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

.table-of-contents {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: green;
}

.post-content {
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.para3 {
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 900px;
  background-color: rgb(118, 122, 179);
}

.myphoto {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: -14em auto;
  margin-left: 90em;
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: 39%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.myclass {
  color: rgb(61, 88, 124);
}
```

```html
<div id="backroundcolourthing">
  <div class="navabr1">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <div>
          <h2>VovaSite</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="barsection">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>
              <a href="Homepage.html">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="aboutme.html">About</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="articles.html">articles</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="articles.html">articles</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="articles.html">articles</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="articles.html">articles</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="home__intro">
        <h2 class="introname"> Hi guys - </h2>
        <p class="introphrase1"> I'm name. I am a soon-to-be-
          <a class="myclass" href="http://www.google.com">Youtuber.</a>
        </p>
        <p class="introphrase3">
          something text boring intresting information lol
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="home__video">
          <img class="myphoto" alt="Pacific" src="img4.jpg" style="
    border-radius: 10px; transform:rotate(0deg);">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if I can understand you, for this case. You would define a width in percentage and then add a new rule in css with a margin auto, this it will do your content be center. (I'm so sorry for my english, I'll hope that you can understand me)

```css
.main{
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="main">
        Content here
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<ul class="nav">`, you can put the css below:

```
ul.nav {
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
}
```

This is the best way in my opinion, but you can put with margin like a `margin: 0 auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way of centering elements I've found is giving the
wrapper/div a width and then providing margins of the elements
you want at the centre, with auto(auto centers the elements
according to the available space). Try:

```
.element{
    Margin-right: auto;
    Margin-left:auto;
}
```

After providing a width to your wrapper class.

```
.barsection {
  margin: right;
}
```

This seems to be a typo in your code.